# SpringBoot MongoDB TimeSeries collection expiration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb to use MongoDB and I am trying to use TimeSeries Collection.

In the URL https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-automatic-removal/#std-label-manual-timeseries-automatic-removal I can find that you can set ExpireAfterSeconds in order that records are removed from collection after set amount of seconds.

However I am unable to do this in springboot repository

```java
@TimeSeries(collection = "temp", timeField = "timestamp", metaField = "probeId", granularity = Granularity.SECONDS)
public final class Temperature {

    public String probeId;
    @Indexed(name = "timestamp", expireAfterSeconds = 60)
    public Instant timestamp;
    public int value;

    public Temperature () {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is being considered.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4099

Should be made available in a future release.